# Cannot see ethereum in main account on mist wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumj

I created a mist wallet yesterday and sent some ethereum to the account address but I cannot see ethereum in the main account. Is there something I'm supposed to do in order to see the ethereum amount populated?